# Batch file to Open an app in IE browser

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer

To check compatibility of an app with certain browsers, i've made a batch file to open a URL using IE

```
@echo OFF
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" (GOTO :X86SUCCESS) ELSE GOTO :NOTSUCCESS
:X86SUCCESS
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\Iexplore.exe" "http://blah.com/blah"
goto END
:NOTSUCCESS
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" (GOTO :X64SUCCESS) ELSE GOTO :NOTSUCCESS1
:X64SUCCESS
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\Iexplore.exe" "http://blah.com/blah"
goto END
:NOTSUCCESS1
:END
```

This should typically open the URL in IE browser since we're directly opening the URL using iexplore, but on some machines this opens up other browsers like Chrome which i'm not sure why, i'm guessing it has to do with default browser setting but since we're opening up IE it shouldn't happen, can anyone explain why this behavior? and how i can open a URL in IE always even if the default browser is not IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start` command interprets the first parameter as the title to display in the window title bar. The path to Internet Explorer will be set as the title and the URI will be shell executed. Therefore, the default browser is started instead.

You could prevent this by specifying an empty title string:

```
setlocal
set "progFiles=%programfiles(x86)%"

if not defined progFiles (
  set "progFiles=%programfiles%"
)

start "" "%progFiles%\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://blah.com/blah"
```

Alternatively, you could also start Internet Explorer like this:

```
start iexplore "http://blah.com/blah"
```

Comment: Correctly said, `start` interprets the first **quoted** parameter as a window title; so it's: `start "" iexplore "..."`

Comment: It seems that `start` interprets the first quoted parameter as a window title **if** the command or program to be executed is quoted as well. Because `iexplore` is not quoted, the quoted string that follows is treated as the first parameter instead.